# What filter does TensorFlow use by default for image filtering?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new at machine learning and I was reading about [CNN with Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) but I have a doubt with this block of code:

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=32,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

According to several articles, there are a lot of filters to apply (Blur, Sharpening, etc). What kind of kernel is Tensorflow applying by default in this kind of code?

Because I'm not specifying any kernel type like:

[image: Edge detection filter]

I'm pretty confused about it, I'll really appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's confusing, but TensorFlow has two `conv2d` methods: `tf.nn.conv2d` and `tf.layers.conv2d`. If you want to filter an image with a known kernel, call `tf.nn.conv2d`. If you want to create a layer in a convolutional neural network (CNN) that will determine its filters programmatically, call `tf.layers.conv2d`.

Comment: Thank you so much! What does programmatically mean? What I mean, how does Tensorflow determines which kernel is better if it depends on the problem?

Comment: When you create a CNN for image classification, you provide input images and identify the category of each image. The CNN's goal is to compute the filters that will make the filtered images easy to categorize. You can read more about them at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network.